# JPA Criteria API - LIKE / OR on relationship

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm trying to implement a search function for an entity shoporder that has 0 to 1 invoice entities assigned to it. I tried the following:

```
root.fetch("invoice", JoinType.LEFT);
query.where(
        builder.or(
        builder.and(
                builder.isNotNull(root.get("invoice")), 
                builder.like(root.get("invoice").get("invoiceNumber"), "%"+filter+"%")),
        builder.like(root.get("buyerCheckoutMessage"), "%"+filter+"%"))
            );
```

I also tried it without the and but it still returns nothing although one of the ORs is true for some items.
Any ideas?

Comment: log the query, and watch the sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Join invoice = root.join("invoice", JoinType.LEFT);
query.where(
        builder.or(
            builder.and(
                builder.isNotNull(invoice), 
                builder.like(invoice.get("invoiceNumber"), "%"+filter+"%")),
            builder.like(root.get("buyerCheckoutMessage"), "%"+filter+"%")));
```